# Double modular exponent with Euler-Fermat

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

$$7^{3^{18}} \pmod{9}$$

Using this formula : $a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod m$

I got $7^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$ and I can write $3^{18}$ as $3^6 \cdot 3^3$

And what are next steps? I got stuck here.

Comment: $3^{18} \equiv 3 \pmod{6}$ so the result is $\equiv 7^3 \pmod{9}$

Answer (score 1):

Without using Euler's Totient Theorem,

$7\equiv-2\pmod9\implies7^3\equiv(-2)^3\equiv1\pmod9$

Now $7^{3r}=(7^3)^r\equiv1^r\pmod9\equiv1$

Here $3r=3^{18}\iff r=3^{18-1}$

Answer (score 1):

By [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):

$$7^{3^{18}}\equiv (1+6)^{3^{18}}\equiv 1+\binom{3^{18}}{1}6\equiv 1\pmod{\! 9}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ and $a$ are co-prime, then:
$$ a^{b^{c}} \equiv (a \mod x)^{(b^c \mod \phi(x))} \mod x$$
$$ \phi(9) = 6$$

$$ 7^{3^{18}} \equiv (7 \mod 9)^{(3^{18} \mod 6)} \mod 9$$
$$ 3^{18} = 9^{9} \equiv 3^{9} = 27^{3} \equiv 3^{3} \equiv 27 \mod 6  = 3 $$
$$ \equiv (7)^{3} \mod 9$$
$$ \equiv 21 \mod 9 $$
$$ \equiv 3 \mod 9 $$

Comment: No, $7^3\equiv (-2)^3\equiv -8\equiv 1\not\equiv 21\pmod{\! 9}$.